# webapi odata, restrict access to entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-web-api, webapp2

For example, we have `Car` object.

```
public class Car 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public City City {get; set;}
}

public class City
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And, on client we make oData request `api/Cars` which return all cars. But, I want to restrict set of records programmaticaly. For example, current user can retrieves only `Cars` from `New York` city. What is best way to do this?

And general question, how to restrict access to entities or properties for different users?

Comment: here is [the reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-security-guidance) you might want to see it..

Comment: This is good for to say `this is good request or not`, but I want to add some query to existing.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the ***"Get"*** method which returns the collection of cars in the controller class to restrict the returned set according to the received Request.

You can save and read cookies to store the information which is used to do this restriction.

Check this for how to use cookies in webapi:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies